# In a trapezoid with perpendicular diagonals the square of sum of the bases is equal to sum of the squares of the diagonals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular to each other. Prove that the square of sum of the bases of the trapezoid is equal to sum of the squares of the diagonals.
>
> [image]

One way to solve this problem is to extend $AB$ from $B$ and then from $C$ drawing a line parallel to  $BD$. Assume the intersection is $F$. Now it can be proven that the quadrilateral $BFCD$ is parallelogram hence $\angle ACF= 90^{\circ}$. And after applying the Pythagorean theorem, the problem is solved. But I'm trying to solve this problem with a different approach, Here we want to prove $$(a+b)^2=(n+q)^2+(m+p)^2$$
$$a^2+b^2+2ab= n^2+q^2+2nq+m^2+p^2+2mp$$
Since $a^2+b^2 = m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2$ the problem is reduced to proving $ab= mp+nq$. Here I'm not sure how to continue. Since $\triangle ABO$ and $\triangle CDO$ are similar triangles we have $\frac ab=\frac mp = \frac nq$ but don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stopped at
$$
\frac ab=\frac mp=\frac nq.
$$

Multiply now both sides of the equation $b^2=p^2+q^2$ by $\displaystyle\frac ab$ to obtain
$$
ab=\frac ab(p^2+q^2)=\frac mpp^2+\frac nqq^2=mp+nq.
$$

Comment: Thanks! It was a clever idea!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{a}{b}=k \implies a=kb, m=kp, n=kq$

Then we have $ab=kb^2, mp+nq=kp^2+kq^2=k(p^2+q^2)=kb^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the approach you had in mind, but I am fond of vector methods in proving geometric statements.

Write $\overrightarrow{AB} = \vec x$, $\overrightarrow{AD} = \vec y$, and note that $\overrightarrow{DC} = \lambda\vec x$ for some scalar $\lambda$ because the quadrilateral is a trapezoid. Let $\overrightarrow{AC}=\vec u = \vec y+\lambda\vec x$ and $\overrightarrow{BD}=\vec v = \vec y - \vec x$ be the diagonals; then we are given $\vec u\cdot \vec v = 0$.

It follows that $\|\vec u\|^2 + \|\vec v\|^2=\|\vec u-\vec v\|^2$. But $\vec u-\vec v = (1+\lambda)\vec x$, and so the sum of the squares of the lengths of the diagonals equals $\|(1+\lambda)\vec x\|^2 = (\|\vec x\|+\|\lambda\vec x\|)^2$, as desired.